# When starting the next loop, how to start from where the previous loop left off?

Tags: python, excel

I want to open 20-30 excel spreadsheets, copy all of their contents and paste it onto one spreadsheet. As it currently stands, my code does the looping just fine however my output file only ends up with the data from the last iteration.

How do I tell my program to start "pasting" from where the last loop left off at?

```
final_file = Workbook()
ws = final_file.active

for i in files:
    if i.endswith(".xlsx"):
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(i)
        sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
        columns = sheet.get_highest_column
        for row in range(2, sheet.get_highest_row()+1):
            for col in range(1, sheet.get_highest_column()+1):
                colletter = get_column_letter(col)
                ws[colletter + str(row)] = sheet[colletter + str(row)].value

    else:
        continue
final_file.save("finalone.xlsx")
```

Comment: If you are talking about the "row" variable, add another variable, say "next_row" and increment it after the ws statement, which would also use next_row instead of row.  And the indentation for the posted code is off.

Comment: Ahh, that's a great idea! Thanks for a super fast response too!

Comment: I was looking through old, unanswered questions and, among others, I found this one which apparently was solved :) - @CurlyJoe - could you convert your comment into an answer? Looks like it solves the problem